# how to find the highest number of items in a table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012, greatest-n-per-group

Im using sql server 2012,I have entries created on different dates,I wish to find on which date i have the maximum number of entries..Does using max() will help me?

Comment: Using `ROW_NUMBER` will help you:

`;WITH Cte AS(
    SELECT *,
        rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY NumEntries DESC)
    FROM tbl
)
SELECT * FROM Cte WHERE rn = 1`

Comment: or select top 1.Number from table order by Number desc

Answer (score 0):

Use group by clause , group your results by date and then select max.

Comment: can you explain using an example

Answer (score 0):

```
select top 1 entry_date from entries group by entry_date order by count(*) desc
```

([SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b9ece/1))